# Routing Read-Write transactions to Primary and Read_only transactions to Replicas using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, tomcat, jpa, entitymanager

I have an application that uses Hibernate/JPA, with Spring and Jersey. In my application context I set the data source, define an entity manager factory, set the transaction manager with that entity manger factory, and have various service methods annotated with the transactional annotation, so I also have the tx:annotation-driven definition to wire in my transaction manager where needed. This setup works great, I've been able to read and write just fine. I would like to move to a DB setup where I have a Master with multiple slaves (MySQL). So I want all the methods annotated with transactional to use a data source pointing to the master db server, and all others to use a connection pool of the slaves.

I've tried creating two different datasources, with two different entity manager factories, and two different persistent units - ugly to say the least. I tried a MySQL Proxy but we had more problems with that then we need. The connection pooling is handled in the servlet container already. Could I implement something in Tomcat that reads the transaction and directs it to the right database server, or is there a way I could get all those methods annotated with the transactional annotation to use a particular datasource?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing and it worked quite well. The entity manager can only have one bean to use as the data source. So what I had to do was to create a bean that routed between the two where necessary. That one ben is the one I used for the JPA entity manager.

I setup two different data sources in tomcat. In the server.xml I created two resources (data sources).

```
<Resource name="readConnection" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="readuser" password="readpass"
          url="jdbc:mysql://readipaddress:3306/readdbname"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"
          removeAbandoned="true" />
<Resource name="writeConnection" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
          username="writeuser" password="writepass"
          url="jdbc:mysql://writeipaddress:3306/writedbname"
          driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
          initialSize="5" maxWait="5000"
          maxActive="120" maxIdle="5"
          validationQuery="select 1"
          poolPreparedStatements="true"
          removeAbandoned="true" />
```

You could have the database tables on the same server, in which case the ip addresses or domain would be the same, just different dbs - you get the jist.

I then added a resource link in the context.xml file in tomcat that referenced these to resources.

```
<ResourceLink name="readConnection" global="readConnection" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
<ResourceLink name="writeConnection" global="writeConnection" type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

These resource links are what spring reads in the application context.

In the application context I added a bean definition for each resource link and added one additional bean definition that referenced a Datasource Router bean I created that takes in a map (enum) of the two previously created beans (bean definition).

```
<!--
Data sources representing master (write) and slaves (read).
-->
<bean id="readDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="readConnection" /> 
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />  
</bean>

<bean id="writeDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="writeConnection" />
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true" />
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="true" />
    <property name="cache" value="true" />
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</bean>

<!--
Provider of available (master and slave) data sources.
-->
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.myapp.dao.DatasourceRouter">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
      <map key-type="com.myapp.api.util.AvailableDataSources">
         <entry key="READ" value-ref="readDataSource"/>
         <entry key="WRITE" value-ref="writeDataSource"/>
      </map>
   </property>
   <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" ref="writeDataSource"/>
</bean>
```

The entity manager bean definition then referenced the dataSource bean.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="${jpa.persistenceUnitName}" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter"> 
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"> 
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.dialect}"/>
            <property name="showSql" value="${jpa.showSQL}" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I defined some properties in a properties file, but you can replace the ${} values with your own specific values. So now I have one bean that uses two other beans that represent my two data sources. The one bean is the one I use for JPA. It's oblivious of any routing happening.

So now the routing bean.

```
public class DatasourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource{

    @Override
    public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey(){
    return DatasourceProvider.getDatasource();
    }

}
```

The overridden method is called by the entity manager to determine the data source basically. The DatasourceProvider has a thread local (thread safe) property with a getter and setter method as well as the clear data source method for clean up.

```
public class DatasourceProvider{
    private static final ThreadLocal<AvailableDataSources> datasourceHolder = new ThreadLocal<AvailableDataSources>();

    public static void setDatasource(final AvailableDataSources customerType){
    datasourceHolder.set(customerType);
    }

    public static AvailableDataSources getDatasource(){
    return (AvailableDataSources) datasourceHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDatasource(){
    datasourceHolder.remove();
    }

}
```

I have a generic DAO implementation with methods I use to handle various routine JPA calls (getReference, persist, createNamedQUery & getResultList, etc.). Before it makes the call to the entityManager to do whatever it needs to do I set the DatasourceProvider's datasource to the read or write. The method can handle that value being passed in as well to make it a little more dynamic. Here is an example method.

```
@Override
public List<T> findByNamedQuery(final String queryName, final Map<String, Object> properties, final int... rowStartIdxAndCount)
{
DatasourceProvider.setDatasource(AvailableDataSources.READ);
final TypedQuery<T> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(queryName, persistentClass);
if (!properties.isEmpty())
{
    bindNamedQueryParameters(query, properties);
}
appyRowLimits(query, rowStartIdxAndCount);

return query.getResultList();
}
```

The AvailableDataSources is an enum with READ or WRITE, which references the appropriate data source. You can see that in the map defined in my bean on the application context.

Comment: Oh, and you need to make sure the MySQL JAR is in Tomcat, otherwise the data sources (resource) won't work.

Comment: Here are some enhancements of this method using custom annotations: http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/

Answer (score 12):

### Spring transaction routing

To route the read-write transactions to the Primary node and read-only transactions to the Replica node, we can define a `ReadWriteDataSource` that connects to the Primary node and a `ReadOnlyDataSource` that connect to the Replica node.

The read-write and read-only transaction routing is done by the Spring [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) abstraction, which is implemented by the `TransactionRoutingDatasource`, as illustrated by the following diagram:

[image: Read-write and read-only transaction routing with Spring]

The `TransactionRoutingDataSource` is very easy to implement and looks as follows:

```
public class TransactionRoutingDataSource 
        extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager
            .isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ?
            DataSourceType.READ_ONLY :
            DataSourceType.READ_WRITE;
    }
}
```

Basically, we inspect the Spring `TransactionSynchronizationManager` class that stores the current transactional context to check whether the currently running Spring transaction is read-only or not.

The `determineCurrentLookupKey` method returns the discriminator value that will be used to choose either the read-write or the read-only JDBC `DataSource`.

The `DataSourceType` is just a basic Java Enum that defines our transaction routing options:

```
public enum  DataSourceType {
    READ_WRITE,
    READ_ONLY
}
```

### Spring read-write and read-only JDBC DataSource configuration

The `DataSource` configuration looks as follows:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(
    basePackages = "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.util.spring.routing"
)
@PropertySource(
    "/META-INF/jdbc-postgresql-replication.properties"
)
public class TransactionRoutingConfiguration 
        extends AbstractJPAConfiguration {

    @Value("${jdbc.url.primary}")
    private String primaryUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.url.replica}")
    private String replicaUrl;

    @Value("${jdbc.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${jdbc.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    public DataSource readWriteDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(primaryUrl);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource readOnlyDataSource() {
        PGSimpleDataSource dataSource = new PGSimpleDataSource();
        dataSource.setURL(replicaUrl);
        dataSource.setUser(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);
        return connectionPoolDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public TransactionRoutingDataSource actualDataSource() {
        TransactionRoutingDataSource routingDataSource = 
            new TransactionRoutingDataSource();

        Map<Object, Object> dataSourceMap = new HashMap<>();
        dataSourceMap.put(
            DataSourceType.READ_WRITE, 
            readWriteDataSource()
        );
        dataSourceMap.put(
            DataSourceType.READ_ONLY, 
            readOnlyDataSource()
        );

        routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceMap);
        return routingDataSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = super.additionalProperties();
        properties.setProperty(
            "hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit",
            Boolean.TRUE.toString()
        );
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] packagesToScan() {
        return new String[]{
            "com.vladmihalcea.book.hpjp.hibernate.transaction.forum"
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String databaseType() {
        return Database.POSTGRESQL.name().toLowerCase();
    }

    protected HikariConfig hikariConfig(
            DataSource dataSource) {
        HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
        int cpuCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(cpuCores * 4);
        hikariConfig.setDataSource(dataSource);

        hikariConfig.setAutoCommit(false);
        return hikariConfig;
    }

    protected HikariDataSource connectionPoolDataSource(
            DataSource dataSource) {
        return new HikariDataSource(hikariConfig(dataSource));
    }
}
```

The `/META-INF/jdbc-postgresql-replication.properties` resource file provides the configuration for the read-write and read-only JDBC `DataSource` components:

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect

jdbc.url.primary=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/high_performance_java_persistence
jdbc.url.replica=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/high_performance_java_persistence_replica

jdbc.username=postgres
jdbc.password=admin
```

The `jdbc.url.primary` property defines the URL of the Primary node while the `jdbc.url.replica` defines the URL of the Replica node.

The `readWriteDataSource` Spring component defines the read-write JDBC `DataSource` while the `readOnlyDataSource` component define the read-only JDBC `DataSource`.

> Note that both the read-write and read-only data sources use HikariCP for connection pooling. For more details about the benefits of using database connection pooling.

The `actualDataSource` acts as a facade for the read-write and read-only data sources and is implemented using the `TransactionRoutingDataSource` utility.

The `readWriteDataSource` is registered using the `DataSourceType.READ_WRITE` key and the `readOnlyDataSource` using the `DataSourceType.READ_ONLY` key.

So, when executing a read-write `@Transactional` method, the `readWriteDataSource` will be used while when executing a `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` method, the `readOnlyDataSource` will be used instead.

> Note that the `additionalProperties` method defines the `hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit` Hibernate property, which I added to Hibernate to postpone the database acquisition for RESOURCE_LOCAL JPA transactions.
>
> Not only that the [`hibernate.connection.provider_disables_autocommit`](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-always-use-hibernate-connection-provider_disables_autocommit-for-resource-local-jpa-transactions/) allows you to make better use of database connections, but it's the only way we can make this example work since, without this configuration, the connection is acquired prior to calling the `determineCurrentLookupKey` method `TransactionRoutingDataSource`.

The remaining Spring components needed for building the JPA `EntityManagerFactory` are defined by the [`AbstractJPAConfiguration`](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/book/hpjp/util/spring/config/jpa/AbstractJPAConfiguration.java) base class.

Basically, the `actualDataSource` is further wrapped by DataSource-Proxy and provided to the JPA `ENtityManagerFactory`. You can check the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence) for more details.

### Testing time

To check if the transaction routing works, we are going to enable the PostgreSQL query log by setting the following properties in the `postgresql.conf` configuration file:

```
log_min_duration_statement = 0
log_line_prefix = '[%d] '
```

The `log_min_duration_statement` property setting is for logging all PostgreSQL statements while the second one adds the database name to the SQL log.

So, when calling the `newPost` and `findAllPostsByTitle` methods, like this:

```
Post post = forumService.newPost(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence",
    "JDBC", "JPA", "Hibernate"
);

List<Post> posts = forumService.findAllPostsByTitle(
    "High-Performance Java Persistence"
);
```

We can see that PostgreSQL logs the following messages:

```
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    BEGIN

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'JDBC', $2 = 'JPA', $3 = 'Hibernate'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select tag0_.id as id1_4_, tag0_.name as name2_4_ 
    from tag tag0_ where tag0_.name in ($1 , $2 , $3)

[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'High-Performance Java Persistence', $2 = '4'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post (title, id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '1'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '2'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = '4', $2 = '3'
[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    insert into post_tag (post_id, tag_id) values ($1, $2)

[high_performance_java_persistence] LOG:  execute S_3: 
    COMMIT
    
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    BEGIN
    
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] DETAIL:  
    parameters: $1 = 'High-Performance Java Persistence'
[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute <unnamed>: 
    select post0_.id as id1_0_, post0_.title as title2_0_ 
    from post post0_ where post0_.title=$1

[high_performance_java_persistence_replica] LOG:  execute S_1: 
    COMMIT
```

The log statements using the `high_performance_java_persistence` prefix were executed on the Primary node while the ones using the `high_performance_java_persistence_replica` on the Replica node.

So, everything works like a charm!

All the source code can be found in my [High-Performance Java Persistence](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/high-performance-java-persistence) GitHub repository, so you can try it out too.

### Conclusion

This requirement is very useful since the [Single-Primary Database Replication](https://vladmihalcea.com/single-primary-database-replication/) architecture not only provides fault-tolerance and better availability, but it allows us to scale read operations by adding more replica nodes.

Comment: Along with your blog I followed this one too - https://fable.sh/blog/splitting-read-and-write-operations-in-spring-boot/  and its working in simple cases. My project is spring boot 2 based and here in my rest controller my one method is doing read and then write. Here the default datasource selected is slave but in the same connection it fails to switch the data. This problem has been reported by many people in different articles. Pasting some of those links here -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561239/abstractroutingdatasource-doesnt-change-connection.

Comment: http://fedulov.website/2015/10/14/dynamic-datasource-routing-with-spring/ here too in comments people reported issues. I wonder if creating 2 different repos say a writeRepo and readRepo containing write and read methods respectively, wired  individually to master and slave datasource is the only solution?

Comment: Worked after setting hibernate.connection.handling_mode to DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION otherwise the lookupKey method is called before setting isCurrentTransactionReadOnly flag.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same kind of need : route the connection between a readonly and writeonly database using a classical MASTER / SLAVE to scale reads.

I end up with a lean solution, using the AbstractRoutingDataSource base class from spring. It allows you to inject a datasource that routes to several datasources based on some conditions that you write.

```
<bean id="commentsDataSource" class="com.nextep.proto.spring.ReadWriteDataSourceRouter">
    <property name="targetDataSources">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String">
            <entry key="READ" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/readdb"/>
            <entry key="WRITE" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/writedb"/>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="defaultTargetDataSource" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/readdb"/>
</bean>
```

And my router simply looks like the following :

```
public class ReadWriteDataSourceRouter extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

@Override
protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
    return TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ? "READ"
            : "WRITE";
}
}
```

I find this quite elegant, but the problem here is that Spring seems to set the transaction to readonly after injecting the datasource, so it does not work. My simple test is to check the result of TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() in my readonly methods (it is true), and in the determineCurrentLookupKey() method where it is false on the same call.

If you got ideas... Anyway you could base the test on anything else other than TransactionSynchronizationManager and this will work fine.

Hope this helps,
Christophe

Comment: did you get it up and running? I have the same issue.

Comment: Use LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy to create your @primary data source. This will get connection obj only when the first db statement is run.

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/kwon37xi/replication-datasource

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="filerp-pcflows" />
    <property name="dataSource" ref="pooledDS" />
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:powercenterCPCPersistence.xml" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <!--<property name="formatSql" value="true" />
            --><property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
            <property name="database" value="DB2" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

-->

```
<bean id="pool" autowire-candidate="false" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="300000"/>
    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="60000"/>
    <property name="maxIdle" value="2"/>
    <property name="minIdle" value="0"/>
    <property name="maxActive" value="8"/>
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="dsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg><ref bean="dataSource" /></constructor-arg>
</bean> 
<bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0"><ref bean="dsConnectionFactory" /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="1"><ref bean="pool" /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="2"><null /></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="3"><value>select 1 from ${cnx.db2.database.creator}.TPROFILE</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="4"><value>false</value></constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg index="5"><value>true</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="pooledDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource"
    depends-on="poolableConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <ref bean="pool" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean> 
<import resource="powercenterCPCBeans.xml"/>
```