# AbstractRoutingDataSource doesn't change connection

Tags: java, spring, datasource

I use `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to change data source dynamically and `ThreadLocal` to set up currentLookupKey. It works nice when I use only one data source per http request. I use `JpaRepository`

```
@Component
@Primary
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Autowired
    private DatabaseMap databaseMap;

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        setTargetDataSources(databaseMap.getSourcesMap());
        setDefaultTargetDataSource(databaseMap.getSourcesMap().get("DEFAULT"));
        super.afterPropertiesSet();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return DatabaseContextHolder.getDatabaseType();
    }

}

public class DatabaseContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> contextHolder = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static void setDatabaseType(String string) {
        contextHolder.set(string);
    }

    public static String getDatabaseType() {
        return (String) contextHolder.get();
    }

    public static void clearDatabaseType() {
        contextHolder.remove();
    }
}
```

When I try to get data in my REST controller I get data only from one database.

Some code in my REST controller

```
DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType("db1");
//here I get data from db1 as expected
//I use JpaRepository
DatabaseContextHolder.clearDatabaseType();
DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType("db2");
//here I should get data from db2 but get from db1
```

I tried to debug and it looks like Spring obtains data source only once in http request.

This method is called only once.

```
@Override
public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return determineTargetDataSource().getConnection();
}
```

Is there any way to force Spring to change data source.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: did you get any solution for this even m facing same problem

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't

Comment: Hey @mariusz2108, did you get any solution to this till date. I just got into the same problem.

Comment: @AnkitSingodia I guess you want to switch multiple times for the same request. Can  you edit question to show where you are switching including any `@Transactional` annotation in the methods ?

Comment: facing same issues

Answer (score 2):

Your problem could be related with transaction delimitation.

When you define a `@Transactional` annotation in your code, Spring will create on your behalf all the stuff necessary to begin and end, and commiting or rollback if required, a transaction.

As you can see in the `doBegin` method in the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/1dcd7f418f2e5a81d5a022f89f83d0f553aea4fb/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/DataSourceTransactionManager.java) of the `DataSourceTransactionManager` class - the same applies to other transaction managers - , Spring obtains a `Connection` when the transaction is initialized - this is why the method `getConnection` is invoked only once - , and it will reuse that connection across all the underlying operations against the database within that transaction (it makes sense for ACID preservation).

So, if you need to connect to several data sources within the same request processing, you can define different methods in you service code, every one annotated with a `@Transactional` annotation, and change the underlying data source as you require before invoke them:

```java
DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType("db1");
// Invoke a service method annotated with @Transactional
// It can use the underlying JpaRepositories that you need
DatabaseContextHolder.clearDatabaseType();
DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseType("db2");
// Invoke again another (or the same, what you need) service method
// annotated with @Transactional, You should get data from db2 this time
```

Comment: The problem is that even after having completing the first transaction, hikari pool doesn't releases the connection and uses the same for the other new transaction as well.

Comment: I understand. Can you please include information in your question about how you are configuring the actual datasources with Hikari?

Comment: Please check it here:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fmdbk7wADVhVsXpDEMq-Gcy5BWhSsNI4nesUWJyHNz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @AnkitSingodia Unless it is required for any other reason, please, can you modify your code in ```DataSourceConfig``` and remove all the ```Bean```s annotations related to the different datasources (```masterDataSource```, ```slaveDataSource```, and ```routingDataSource```) and the Hikari configurations? When you initialize the entity manager factory you are actually creating all the required stuff when you set its datasource: ```em.setDataSource(routingDataSource())```. There is no need to declare also these objects as beans, it will be duplicated in the Spring context. Can you try and see?

Comment: Please, can you also complete the google docs document with the source code of your controller and service classes? I think it would be of help.

Comment: @AnkitSingodia I think the problem must be related with your configuration or with Hikari. I downloaded a similar example from this [link](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/11/27/tutorial-de-spring-dynamic-datasource/). In the example they have two datasources ruled by ```AbstractRoutingDataSource```. Although they use XML configuration instead of Java configuration, all the software is very similar to the one you describe. In the method ```getTeams``` of the ```TeamController``` class that they define, I just did a simple test (please, see next comment), and it works as expected.

Comment: ```@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Team> getTeams(@RequestParam(required = false, value = COUNTRY) String code) {
    CountryDbContextHolder.setDbType(mapLeagues.get("ES"));
    List<Team> teamsSpain = teamService.getTeams();
    CountryDbContextHolder.clearDb();
    CountryDbContextHolder.setDbType(mapLeagues.get("DE"));
    List<Team> teamsDeusch = teamService.getTeams();
    teamsSpain.addAll(teamsDeusch);
    return teamsSpain;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `spring.jpa.open-in-view` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

- My suspicion here is you have a method annotated with `@Transactional` annotation. Before calling that transactional method, you first specify one datasource key and you call the transactional method.Inside the transactional method, you first call repository and it works as expected with datasource look up key you set. However then you set different key, inside the transactional method, and call another repository and it still uses the key you set first time.
- `DataSource` will be chosen by the framework when the `transaction` starts so **if you are using `@Transactional` annotation, whatever switching you do inside the method is useless.** Because the datasource would have been chosen by proxy created for `@Transactional` annotation. Best option is to have the branching logic in non transactional service or use `TransactionTemplate` instead of `@Transactional`
- For example, make sure `YourRestController` does not have class level `@Transactional` as well as no `@Transactional` annotation in this `yourRestControllerMethod`, you will keep them to your service.

```
     @RestController
     public class YourRestController {

      @Autowired
      TransactionalService transactional

      public void yourRestControllerMethod(){
        //set the datasource look up key to A1 and then
        transactional.methodA1();
        //change datasource look up key to A2 and then
        transactional.methodA2();
      }

     }
```

```
    @Service
    public class TransactionalService {

       @Transactional
       public void methodA1(){

       }
       
       @Transactional
       public void methodA2() {

       }

    }
```

Comment: We have exactly a same setup. I debugged the problem and it boils down to the fact that:

When the first transaction begins --> the datasource key is resolved -> hikari pool try creating a new connection within which it used a map of predefined (in config) datasources map and fetches the correct datasource.

But then when the new transaction begins --> the datasource key is again resolved (as expected) --> BUT this time, the hikari pool doesn't tries fetching a new connection and rather uses the older one and hence it never uses the datasource map this time.

Comment: Nope, I'm still searching for a fix :(

Comment: Can you add your HikariDataSource configuration and any related properties both datasources?

Comment: Please check it here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fmdbk7wADVhVsXpDEMq-Gcy5BWhSsNI4nesUWJyHNz0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is in `getHibernatePropertiesMaster()`?

Comment: There are two datasources and with their own connection pool. So as long as when the second transaction begins, it goes to routing datasource, it does the looking, then routing datasource should pickup the `slaveHikari` datasource. slaveHikari datasource is free to reuse its connection from its own pool because it is pointing slave database anyway.

Comment: So when you are debugging can you take note of the object reference for `masterDatasource` and `slaveDataSource`, and see the datasource reference picked up by routing datasource is different from the first one?

Comment: Can you please do one more thing for me to rule out you are not mixing up properties? If you are doing master first and slave second, can you switch it to slave first and master second. As per your bug, in first scenario,  both calls should go to master only and in in first scenario, both calls should go to slave  db only. If both scenarios go to master, you are mixing up the properties

Comment: I just added the getHibernatePropertiesMaster() to the same google doc. 

For your recent comment, when I try with master first and slave second, then both the transactions works using master datasource . And when I do slave txn first and master txn second, then it uses slave datasource for both the txns (though it fails on second one as I'm trying to do a write operation there)

Comment: I've also added a code snippet from one of the hikari jar class file, which tries fetching a connection (but sadly only at the time of first transaction in an http request)

Comment: Unfortunately no lock. In What class has `Connection newConnection()` method. I can't see it in `HikariDataSource` class?

Comment: It's in PoolBase.java in com.zaxxer.hikari.pool package

Comment: Facing similar kind of issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76136715/transactionsynchronizationmanager-iscurrenttransactionreadonly-always-returnin

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, none of the above solution could fix it.. but making my Service method **final** (in my REST Controller)

```
public final Response
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I followed the [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63244648/917499) from jccampanero and it work: separating two methods in the service class, each method has a database connection with a different data source, switching datasource by `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.

I think the key point here is the database configuration where we give the `AbstractRoutingDataSource` to `EntityManagerFactory` and `TransactionManager` instead of `DataSource` as normal.

```
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ReadOnlyContext.isReadOnly() ? DSType.READ_ONLY : DSType.WRITE;
    }
}
```

and the DatabaseConfiguration:

```
@Bean
public RoutingDataSource actualDataSource(
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource readWriteDataSource,
    @Qualifier("dataSourceReadOnly") DataSource readOnlyDataSource
) {
    Map<Object, Object> targetDataSources = new HashMap<>();
    targetDataSources.put(DSType.READ_ONLY, readOnlyDataSource);
    targetDataSources.put(DSType.WRITE, readWriteDataSource);

    RoutingDataSource routingDataSource = new RoutingDataSource();
    routingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(targetDataSources);
    routingDataSource.setDefaultTargetDataSource(readOnlyDataSource);

    return routingDataSource;
}

@Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    RoutingDataSource actualDataSource
) {
    return builder.dataSource(actualDataSource).packages("the.domain.package").persistenceUnit("persistenUnitName").build();
}

@Bean(name = "transactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(RoutingDataSource actualDataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(actualDataSource);
}
```

With the above configuration, JPA Repositories will use the `entityManagerFactory` bean to obtain DB connections (in each service method, Spring will call the method `determineCurrentLookupKey` in `RoutingDataSource` to get the datasource we specified before).