# Spring JPA: How to update 2 different tables in 2 different `DataSource` in the same request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

In our application, we have a common database called `central` and every customer will have their own database with exactly the same set of tables. Each customer's database might be hosted on our own server or the customer's server based on the requirement of the customer organization.

To handle this multi-tenant requirement, we're extending the `AbstractRoutingDataSource` from Spring JPA and overriding the `determineTargetDataSource()` method to create a new `DataSource` and establish a new connection on the fly based on the incoming `customerCode`. We also use a simple `DatabaseContextHolder` class to store the current datasource context in a `ThreadLocal` variable. Our solution is similar to what is describe in this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source).

Let's say in a single request, we'll need to update some data in both the `central` database and the customer's database as following.

```
public void createNewEmployeeAccount(EmployeeData employee) {
    DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseContext("central");
    // Code to save a user account for logging in to the system in the central database

    DatabaseContextHolder.setDatabaseContext(employee.getCustomerCode());
    // Code to save user details like Name, Designation, etc. in the customer's database
}
```

This code would only work if `determineTargetDataSource()` is called every time **just before** any SQL queries gets executed so that we can switch the `DataSource` dynamically half way through our method.

However, from this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561239/abstractroutingdatasource-doesnt-change-connection), it seems like `determineTargetDataSource()` is only called once for each `HttpRequest` when a `DataSource` is being retrieved for the very first time in that request.

I'd be very grateful if you can give me some insights into when `AbstractRoutingDataSource.determineTargetDataSource()` actually gets called. Besides, if you've dealt with a similar multi-tenant scenario before, I'd love to hear your opinion on how I should deal with the updating of multiple `DataSource` in a single request.

Comment: May I know which Spring Boot version are you using?

Comment: @IanLim: I'm using the 2.1.1 version :)

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27614301/spring-boot-multiple-datasource can help. Main idea - make use of @Primary annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found a working solution, which is a mix of static data source settings for our `central` database and dynamic data source settings for our customer's database.

In essence, we know exactly which table comes from which database. Hence, we were able to separate our `@Entity` classes into 2 different packages as following.

```
com.ft.model
   -- central
      -- UserAccount.java
      -- UserAccountRepo.java
   -- customer
      -- UserProfile.java
      -- UserProfileRepo.java
```

Subsequently, we created two `@Configuration` classes to set up the data source setting for each package. For our `central` database, we use static settings as following.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.ft.model.central" }
)
public class CentralDatabaseConfiguration {
    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create(this.getClass().getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                .url("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=central")
                .username("sa")
                .password("mhsatuck")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.ft.model.central")
                .persistenceUnit("central")
                .build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager (@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

For the `@Entity` in the `customer` package, we set up dynamic data source resolver using the following `@Configuration`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "customerEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "customerTransactionManager",
        basePackages = { "com.ft.model.customer" }
)
public class CustomerDatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean(name = "customerDataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new MultitenantDataSourceResolver();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customerEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder, @Qualifier("customerDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .packages("com.ft.model.customer")
                .persistenceUnit("customer")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "customerTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("customerEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

In the `MultitenantDataSourceResolver` class, we plan to maintain a `Map` of the created `DataSource` using `customerCode` as key. From each incoming request, we will get the `customerCode` and inject it into our `MultitenantDataSourceResolver` to get the correct `DataSource` within the `determineTargetDataSource()` method.

```
public class MultitenantDataSourceResolver extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    @Autowired
    private Provider<CustomerWrapper> customerWrapper;

    private static final Map<String, DataSource> dsCache = new HashMap<String, DataSource>();

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        try {
            return customerWrapper.get().getCustomerCode();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource determineTargetDataSource() {
        String customerCode = (String) this.determineCurrentLookupKey();

        if (customerCode == null)
            return MultitenantDataSourceResolver.getDefaultDataSource();
        else {
            DataSource dataSource = dsCache.get(customerCode);
            if (dataSource == null)
                dataSource = this.buildDataSourceForCustomer();

            return dataSource;
        }
    }

    private synchronized DataSource buildDataSourceForCustomer() {
        CustomerWrapper wrapper = customerWrapper.get();

        if (dsCache.containsKey(wrapper.getCustomerCode()))
            return dsCache.get(wrapper.getCustomerCode() );
        else {
            DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create(MultitenantDataSourceResolver.class.getClassLoader())
                    .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                    .url(wrapper.getJdbcUrl())
                    .username(wrapper.getDbUsername())
                    .password(wrapper.getDbPassword())
                    .build();

            dsCache.put(wrapper.getCustomerCode(), dataSource);

            return dataSource;
        }
    }

    private static DataSource getDefaultDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create(CustomerDatabaseConfiguration.class.getClassLoader())
                .driverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")
                .url("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=central")
                .username("sa")
                .password("mhsatuck")
                .build();
    }
}
```

The `CustomerWrapper` is a `@RequestScope` object whose values will be populated on each request by the `@Controller`. We use `java.inject.Provider` to inject it into our `MultitenantDataSourceResolver`.

Lastly, even though, logically, we will never save anything using the default `DataSource` because all requests will always contain a `customerCode`, at startup time, there is no `customerCode` available. Hence, we still need to provide a valid default `DataSource`. Otherwise, the application will not be able to start.

If you have any comments or a better solution, please let me know.