# SPR-16876 TransactionSynchronizationManager not returning correct values in implementation of AbstractRoutingDataSource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data, spring-transactions

I am following this link https://vladmihalcea.com/read-write-read-only-transaction-routing-spring/ to set up the database master and replica instance in my spring boot app. The only difference is I am not using Hibernate or JPA.

**Found out issue already exist in Spring Framework. Please refer to this https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16876?redirect=false**

My service class is annotated with `@Transactional(readOnly = true)`.

But in the implementation of RoutingDataSource, I always get `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()` as false and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName()` as null in `determineCurrentLookupKey()`.

```
@Slf4j
public class RoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {
    public enum Route {
        PRIMARY, REPLICA
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        log.info("ReadOnly? " + TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()); //Returns false always
        log.info("Tx Name " + (TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName())); //Returns null always
        return TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly() ? Route.REPLICA : Route.PRIMARY;
    }
}
```

If I log the same in my service method, I get `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly()` as true and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName()` with a not-null value.

```
@Service
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public class DatabaseTestingService {
    public List<String> replica() {
        System.out.println("--> " + (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isCurrentTransactionReadOnly())); //Returns True
        System.out.println("--> " + (TransactionSynchronizationManager.getCurrentTransactionName())); //Returns Trx name
        ...
    }
}
```

As `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` is set on my service class, it should default call to the read-only db instance but it is always calling read-write db instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked into the `AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java`. The logic to start new transaction is written inside the `startTransaction()` as below

```
private TransactionStatus startTransaction(TransactionDefinition definition, Object transaction,
        boolean debugEnabled, @Nullable SuspendedResourcesHolder suspendedResources) {

    boolean newSynchronization = (getTransactionSynchronization() != SYNCHRONIZATION_NEVER);
    DefaultTransactionStatus status = newTransactionStatus(
            definition, transaction, true, newSynchronization, debugEnabled, suspendedResources);
    doBegin(transaction, definition); //Transaction is getting built here and connection is getting acquired here based on RoutingDataSource.determineCurrentLookupKey()
    prepareSynchronization(status, definition); //Transaction is getting synchronized after the connection is built
    return status;
}
```

As you can see in the above code transaction is getting synchronized after connection is acquired. So `RoutingDataSource.determineCurrentLookupKey()` will not be called after `prepareSynchronization(status, definition)`.

To synchronize the transaction before the connection is getting acquired I extended the DataSourceTransactionManager and wrote logic as below

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomTransactionManager extends DataSourceTransactionManager {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public CustomTransactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
        super(dataSource);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doBegin(Object transaction, TransactionDefinition definition) {
        if (definition.getName().contains("package_substring")) {
            log.debug(String.format("Init. Transaction for MyApp Service: %s : %s", definition.getName(),
                    definition));
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionIsolationLevel(
                    definition.getIsolationLevel() != TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_DEFAULT
                    ? definition.getIsolationLevel()
                            : null);
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionReadOnly(definition.isReadOnly());
            TransactionSynchronizationManager.setCurrentTransactionName(definition.getName());
        }
        super.doBegin(transaction, definition);
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for my in Springboot3

Answer (score 1):

As of Spring 6.1.2 you can just use `LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy` and set the readonly datasource rather than deal with implementing a custom `AbstractRoutingDataSource`

```
LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy lazyDateSource = new LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy(dataSource);
lazyDateSource.setReadOnlyDataSource(dataSourceReader);
```

This should do the routing based on the `@Transactional(readonly=true)` automagically. Additional conversation can be found on [the issue tracker](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21415)